# How to 'exit 1' if this find script returns results

Tags: shell, scripting, find

I am not extremely familiar with scripting, but I am trying to learn. I have come across a script I need to use to run a check on a build process in Xcode. If this find operation returns results, I need to 'exit 1'. Or stop the build.

```
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" |
  perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ error: \$1/"
```

So what can I do to exit if I find something but don't if I don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the exit status of a pipeline is the status of the last command in the pipeline.  So, you want the `perl` process to exit with 1 if it prints anything and to exit with 0 if it does not.

```
perl -p -e "\$match = 1 if s/($TAGS)/ error: \$1/; END { exit \$match; }"
```

NB: space added before `error`.

---

Testing:

```
$ cat so15307298.sh
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
SRCROOT=.
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" |
perl -p -e "\$match = 1 if s/($TAGS)/ error: \$1/; END { exit \$match; }"
$ echo "TODO: this is a problem" > x1.h
$ echo "FIXME: this is a problem too" > x2.h
$ echo "Allez oop" > x3.h
$ sh -x so15307298.sh
+ TAGS='TODO:|FIXME:'
+ SRCROOT=.
+ find . '(' -name '*.h' -or -name '*.m' ')' -print0
+ xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching '(TODO:|FIXME:).*$'
+ perl -p -e '$match = 1 if s/(TODO:|FIXME:)/error: $1/; END { exit $match; }'
./x1.h:1: error: TODO: this is a problem
./x2.h:1: error: FIXME: this is a problem too
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works, but the error no longer shows up on the line it occurs (it did before). It just shows up as a generic shell script invocation error. I don't know if you know enough about scripting in Xcode, just thought I'd check :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing.  When I type 'TODO: xxxx' or 'FIXME: yyyy' at the Perl script, it prepends `error:` to the message (and exits with status 1).  If none of the lines contains a match, then it exits with status 0.  I'm assuming you simply updated the `perl` command of your script.  (I tried it with the `find` and `xargs` as in the question, and it seemed to produce the answer I expected.  Please clarify your problem — there's probably a simple explanation and/or fix.

Comment: Just updated my question with some more detail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm: I see I lost a space before the word `error` in my substitute; does that make the difference?

Comment: That did it! I really appreciate your help. You are my hero. And your point total on here is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
FILES=$(find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0)
if [ "x$FILES" == "x" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```